# Fields 'workOrder' do not exist in the CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have a CSV file with several rows and each row has a work order number under column titled "W.O.No."

Here's what I'm doing:
I created a class called Job, with a single field.

```
class Job
{
    public int workOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created a JobMap class

```
class JobMap : CsvClassMap<Job>
{
    public override void CreateMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.workOrder).Name("W.O.No.");
    }
}
```

And finally, this is my main code

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filePath);
var csv = new CsvReader(file);
var record = csv.GetRecords<Job>().ToList();
```

For whatever reason I'm getting an error saying

> Fields 'workOrder' do not exist in the CSV file.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems that in you code missing map initialization.  Try to add `csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<JobMap>();`

This code should work:

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filePath);
var csv = new CsvReader(file);
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<JobMap>();
var record = csv.GetRecords<Job>().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, configuration class registration was not very intuitive in the official documentation